# How to fill out some fields based on a given criterion?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df:
NEW  COL1  COL2
1    2     9
3    NaN   NaN
0    7     NaN

column_names = [COL1,COL2]
```

I want to set values of TOTAL to be equal to NEW, only when NEW > 0 and the sum over COL1 and COL2 in a row is equal to 0.

This is how I do it, but the result is incorrect (i.e. COL1 are equal to 0 in corresponding rows). For instance in the second row COL1 would need to be equal to 3, but it is equal to 0.

```
df[column_names] = df[column_names].fillna(0)
df.COL1.where((df.NEW>0 & (df[column_names].sum(axis=1) == 0)),df.NEW)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DataFrame.apply` with `axis=1` (to apply the func to each row) and in that function do your logic. Example -

```
df['TOTAL'] = df.apply((lambda row: row[col_names].sum() or row['NEW']), axis=1)
```

Demo -

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   NEW  COL1  COL2
0    1     2     9
1    3   NaN   NaN
2    0     7   NaN

In [13]: df['TOTAL'] = df.apply((lambda row: row[col_names].sum() or row['NEW']), axis=1)

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
   NEW  COL1  COL2  Total
0    1     2     9     11
1    3   NaN   NaN      3
2    0     7   NaN      7
```

---

The issue with your [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) method is that `Series.where` returns the value from `Col1` if the condition is true, otherwise it returns value from `NEW` . So this would return `NEW` value only where condition is met (This is actually opposite of your requirement) .

This is explained in [the documentations -](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html)

> **`Series.where(cond, other=nan, inplace=False, axis=None, level=None, try_cast=False, raise_on_error=True)`**
>
> Return an object of same shape as self and whose corresponding entries are from self where cond is True and otherwise are from other.

So what you wanted to do was the negation of what you are doing right now. Example -

```
In [22]: df.COL1.where((df.NEW>0 & (df[column_names].sum(axis=1) == 0)),df.NEW)
Out[22]:
0     2
1   NaN
2     0
Name: COL1, dtype: float64

In [23]: df.COL1.where(~(df.NEW>0 & (df[column_names].sum(axis=1) == 0)),df.NEW)
Out[23]:
0    1
1    3
2    7
Name: COL1, dtype: float64
```

Please also note `df.COL1` returns the new series, it is not inplace, you may want to assign it back to `df['COL1']` .

Comment: I appreciate if you could also explain what was wrong in my "where" statement. Thank.s

Comment: One thing. I don't need to create a new column Total. I want to put this value in COL1.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos You said you wanted `TOTAL` . Quoting from Question - *I want to set values of TOTAL to be equal to NEW, only when NEW > 0 and the sum over COL1 and COL2 in a row is equal to 0.* . If you want similar behavior for `COL1` , use `COL1` instead of `TOTAL` .

Comment: @KlausosKlausos Also I have updated what the issue with your method was and a fix for that as well.